# What should i load from collada files, in order to see my 3D model in c++?

Tags: c++, parsing, opengl, collada

i have a problem loading a model in my c++ opengl glut project, i created a parser which gets in  and its  node, but if i try to load from those vertexes i see my model streched, i can only see the shape but the inner parts like doors or walls have some triangles missing, my program is more than 3,000+ characters(source code) and i use my Android phn here to post the question, theres no error in my program only it does is get the file position of  and another function will use that position to read and convert string data into floats, then opengl display function uses those floats to render models, so my question is why is my model dont looks the same as i created?

EDIT: No, small cube is one file, and the other i made is over 4+ mb, and i dont mean by dont want to show, i said can't show, how can one write huge 3000+ chars long source code, and 10000+ chars long file with a phone?? Sorry i also know it might help u answering my question, and i must provide it but i'am unable to write the whole code, and i know my loader is wrong because it just looks in  of  and convert it to floating point value and the draw function uses it to draw on a 3d world. Pls tell me what things should i take in order to only load vertices from any file, not just a specific one...

Comment: Are you aware that the indices are stored in a special way in collada files?

Comment: No, i just know that the <float_array> in <library_geometries> contains vertices, am i wrong? And can u pls clear it...

Comment: Normally a collada file also contains an array of indices which tells what the order is in which we should render the vertices.

Comment: Collada allows the same thing to be done in so many different ways that it would be very hard to handle every possible option. There are *very* big libraries like fcollada, opencollada or colladadom which targets exactly that. If you want to write your own loader, you should start with COLLADA specification (huge 500+ pages document, by the way). Aside from that - I don't think anyone here could help you without seeing code and sample data. But yes, in short you should load arrays, and dereference them with indices (different attributes may have different indices).

Comment: I have a small cube.dae created from sketchup, it's verry small and after analysing the .dae file i found that vertices or floating point values are stored in <float_array> so i thought it might be vertices i load those vertices in my program, same like it i created a large .dae file in sketchup, and after loading and drawing model with the floats in <float_array> to </float_array> the problem i found is the model draws which i did'nt made, i mean streched model or missing triangles spaces found in walls, so can u tell me in short what should i extract from the file??

Comment: Show us the geometry part of your file.

Comment: It's verry big, thats why i did'nt even posted my source code, i use my Mobile phone to question here, but theres no error in the file too, i tried importing it with sketchup, it looks fine, but when loading with my loader which just loads floats from the first <float_array> node then a draw function call is called to load it, i even tried loading Astroboy_max/maya.dae, but those cannot be displayed also i set the glortho() manually by analysing which float value is greatest, if found 53.8988 i set ortho to 100, is it ok?

Comment: 'small cube.dae' is 'very big'. What the?.. But okay, if you don't want to show neither data nor code - the only answer could be "your loader is wrong".

Comment: Read specification. Look for `polylist` tag. Here look for `input` tags. Find all inputs by their names. Take indices from `p` tag - first index specifies index in first input, second in second, and so on; look in `vcount` tag to see how many vertices this polygon have. And implement completely different loading in case your file have `triangles` tag instead of `polylist` (specification allows that). Then if you'll still want to load every possible variant - you'll end up with something like `opencollada`'s 500k+ lines of code library.